# Laravel Request Validations with Mutator

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have database columns in snake case so i have define mutator in my model class to use Camel Case. In update method of controller i am expecting a custom Request parameter. In the validation method do i need to specify the rules for both Snake Case and Camel or is there any way so i can avoid duplicate code for rule validations. Below is sample code for mutator, request and controller.

```
//Mutator
public function setLogoWidthAttribute($value){
        $this->attributes['logo_width']=$value;
    }
//Request
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'sometimes|required|max:500',
            'logo'=>'sometimes|max:50',
            'logoWidth'=>'sometimes|digits_between:1,3|numeric' ,
            'logo_width'=>'sometimes|digits_between:1,3|numeric'
        ];
    }
//Controller 
public function update(OrgRequest $request, Org $org)
    {
...
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question but mapping all snake_case and camelCase attributes is an overkill and won't scale. I wouldn't recommend to do it. Use snake_case and map the camelCase input to it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please give some examples for your recommendations.